# Hide pagination buttons in table header of p:dataTable

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using `<p:dataTable>` of PrimeFaces 3.3.1 with pagination. The pagination buttons appear in both the table header and footer. I would like to hide the pagination buttons in the table header and keep the ones in the table footer. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

According to the [PrimeFaces Users Guide](http://primefaces.org/documentation.html) and the [`<p:dataTable>` VDL Documentation](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.2/p/dataTable.html), there's a `paginatorPosition` attribute which can take a value of `both` (default), `top` or `bottom`.

So just set `paginatorPosition` attribute to `bottom`.

```
<p:dataTable ... paginatorPosition="bottom">
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative for hidding all datatable paginators on headers:

```
.ui-paginator-top{
    display:none;
}
```